# Big xml files over FTP

Tags: php, ftp

On my FTP server, there is a 4gb XML file and I want it to put data from that file to the database using PHP.

I know how to connect to FTP and basic operations using PHP but my question is there a possibility to do it without having to download the file first?

Comment: What do you mean by *download file first*?

Comment: [fseek](http://php.net/fseek/) worth a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you cannot "stream" file using FTP as you could do say on network drive. It's not possible to open that file without downloading it first locally.

This is given you can only access that file via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

If your FTP server and PHP server are one and the same, you just need to change the path to reference the FTP location rather than whereever you are downloading to.

If they are on the same local network, you may be able to use a network path to reach the file.

Otherwise, you will indeed need to transfer the entire file first by downloading it.